# Return groups in Regular Expression matched by string

Tags: python, regex

Suppose we have the following regular expression:

```
[ABC]{1,3}.{0,2}[DEFG].{2,3}V
```

We can test with Python's `re` module if this matches the following string:

```
AXDXXV
```

It does match. Then, using Python, how could we retrieve each part of the regular expression matched by each part of the string?

For example, the following output list would work:

```
[ '[ABC]{1,3}', '.{0,2}', '[DEFG]', '.{2,3}', 'V' ]
```

Comment: Wrap each part with the capturing group - http://ideone.com/Wzd1G7

Comment: I don't think such level of introspecture is supported, you need to change (add some capture groups to) your regular expression

Answer (score 4):

You may use *named capturing groups* and after obtaining a match you will be able to get the values mapped to those names (with [`groupDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict)). I also advise to build such a pattern dynamically as an *OrderedDict*.

See a [Python 2.7 demo](http://ideone.com/2QuXUx):

```
import re, collections

# Define the pattern parts with named capturing groups
parts = [('p1', r'(?P<p1>[ABC]{1,3})'),
    ('p2', r'(?P<p2>.{0,2})'),
    ('p3', r'(?P<p3>[DEFG])'),
    ('p4', r'(?P<p4>.{2,3})'),
    ('p5', r'(?P<v>V)')]
# Create and init the OrderedDict
pod = collections.OrderedDict(parts)
# Build the pattern from values (in Python 3, use list(pod.items()) )
reg = "".join([v for k,v in pod.items()])
test_str = "AXDXXV"
# Find a match
m = re.search(reg, test_str)
if m:
    # If a match is found, get the groupdict()
    m_dict = m.groupdict()
    print(m_dict)
    print("{} => {}".format(m.group("p1"), pod["p1"]))
```

The regex will look like `(?P<p1>[ABC]{1,3})(?P<p2>.{0,2})(?P<p3>[DEFG])(?P<p4>.{2,3})(?P<v>V)`, and once a match is found, you will get something like 
`{'p2': 'X', 'p3': 'D', 'p1': 'A', 'p4': 'XX', 'v': 'V'}`. Then, you may always check the underlying pattern with a value with `"{} => {}".format(m.group("p1"), pod["p1"])` (e.g. `A => (?P<p1>[ABC]{1,3})`).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew. This would work, but only if one can define the pattern parts in advance. Would it be possible to have these parts recognized automatically after they match the string? For example, here the first 'A' will be recognized by this part of  the regex: `[ABC]{1,3}`, then how can we get the output list with `[ABC]{1,3}` as its first element?

Comment: There is no way after that other than parsing the pattern.